# How do SNI clients send server_name in CLIENT HELLO

Tags: sni

I hope i am at the right place asking this question, its regarding understanding of SNI

According to https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ssl-profiles-part-7-server-name-indication#.U5wEnfmSzOz
"With the introduction of SNI, the client can indicate the name of the server to which he is attempting to connect as part of the "Client Hello" message in the handshake process"

My question is how does client like browser or any HTTP client (say java.net) send this server name in CLIENT HELLO?? Does client do by itself or you have to add it Programmatically to https request (e.g how  in JAVA.net HttpsURLConnection)

Reading from http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4366.txt 
"Currently, the only server names supported are DNS hostnames"
so the hostname is the server_name sent by SNI complient client or any other name can be sent by the client..

I hope i am clear, do improve the question/wording if its unclear or let me know if its not clear 
thanks

Comment: I fear that this is homework, which generally makes it off-topic.

Comment: not homework, just trying to understand SNI and explain it to a client, i am connecting to a SNI Server via HTTPS (android java.net httpsurlconnection) he is saying send server name along with the https request, according to my finding hostname is used as server name by SSL library, just wanted to clear that up

Comment: Oh, yes, it's a feature of the TLS protocol.  I don't recall the specifics, however.  The DNS lookup and the TLS SNI are two separate processes, technically, even though any sane user agent will use the same name for both (i.e. the TLS exchange doesn't know anything or care about the name resolution process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an https library, which you can give a URL and the library will fetch the contents of that URL for you, then the clean way to add SNI support is to perform it entirely within the library.

It is the library which parses the URL to find the hostname, the caller will never know which part of the URL is the hostname, so the caller couldn't tell the library which hostname to send in the SNI request. If the caller had to somehow figure out the hostname in order to tell this to the library, then that would be a poorly designed library.

You might look a level deeper in the software stack and find that an https library might be building on top of an SSL library. In such a case even the https library does not need to know about SNI. The https library would simply tell the SSL library, that it want a connection to a particular hostname. The SSL library would resolve the hostname to get IP address to connect to, the SSL library would also be performing the SSL handshake during which the client may send a hostname as part of SNI and the server send a hostname as part of a certificate for the client to verify.

During connection setup, the SSL client library need to use the hostname for three different purposes. It would be trivial to support the usage of three different hostnames for those three purposes. The https library already know the hostname, and passing that hostname three times to the SSL library rather than just one wouldn't be any significant amount of additional work. But it would hardly make sense to support this anyway.

In fact SNI could be entirely transparent to the https library. It would make sense to extend the SSL library with SNI support without changing the API to the https library. There is little reason to turn off SNI support in a client, which supports it. So defaulting to having SNI enabled makes sense.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer, just what i needed to confirm , the SSL library would send the hostname for SNI, other than the HOSTNAME the caller cannot add a separate (other than the hostname) server name or something.. right ?

Comment: @baboo Technically it would be possible to implement a library such that you could pass another name to the library. I just don't see how it could make sense for an https library to use any other hostname than the one it found inside the URL.

Comment: @baboo I don't know the particular library you are using. I know enough about the protocol stack to say what makes sense. My knowledge about SNI came from what I needed to learn in order to add SNI support to http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/